# Two column float with [b] using the cas-dc template

Tags: floats, els-cas

I am using the `cas-dc` template for Elsevier. 
When trying to use

```
\begin{figure*}[pos=b]
content
\end{figure*}
```

the illustration is not shown at the bottom of the page, but still at the top.
I have included `\usepackage{stfloats}`. I don't see anything mentioned that strictly forbids it, unless I missed this. Anyone know why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please provide us with a compilable example of your document that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to put the figure at the bottom of the *first* page?

Comment: I want to put the figure at the bottom of the current page.